Как удобно отлаживать php и js одновременно
Есть рабочее место, например: Windows, apache, mysql.
Есть например wordpress локально.
Php в принципе через vs code нормально отлаживается
Но вот js только пока отладчиком браузера могу отлаживать и как-то не удобно.
Кто какие варианты использует? Лучше софт без таблеток, не хакнутые.
Мне в основном для отладки плагинов для CMS.

А в чём неудобство? Такой же отладчик, те же watch, те же точки останова и т.д.

У @KAGGDesign есть несколько полезнейших митапов по отладке ВП. Настоятельно рекомендую.

Почему неудобно в браузере? Ничего не помещается, приходится чего+то постоянно раздвигать. И глобального поиска нет, чтобы быстро найти нужную функцию и поставить точку останова. И локальные переменные быстро не посмотреть. И хочется спросить, а вам удобно? Примечание: не могу найти здесь на форуме как ответить на конкретную запись (опять не удобно)
